# Create Report in Embedded Power BI with GenerateTokenRequestV2

Tags: javascript, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have a powerBI embedded into a web application. The app contains a feature to create new reports as well that will save it into a workspace with the specified dataset.

The new experience workspaces came up with the dataset sharing capability, that'll enable users to create reports across multiple workspaces but using the dataset from one workspace. I've used the [GenerateTokenRequestV2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embedtoken/generatetoken) to generate the embed token and used the Microsoft client library for JS [PowerBI-Client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/powerbi-client) to embed the same.

Am able to successfully embed and work on creating the report with the specified dataset, but there is an error thrown up on trying to save the report.
The network tab shows a call with endpoint "https://wabi-west.../explore/explorations?name={Report Name}" returning 403 status code.

The config sent to powerbi-client library:

```
{
      type: 'report',
      tokenType: 1,
      accessToken: '__access_token__',
      embedUrl 'https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed',
      datasetId: '__shared_datasetID__',
      groupId: '__target_workspaceID__',
}
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a list of [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal#considerations-and-limitations) with using a shared dataset in embedded report creation mode as per the original documentation.

Answer (score 5):

There can be 2 issues here.

**Missing Scopes**

Please check whether your AAD app has the scopes you need for saving the report. You need `Report.ReadWriteAll` and `Dataset.ReadWriteAll`.

You can change the permissions from here Azure Portal by going in the App registrations.

Update the permissions and try again.

**Role Level**

As a user of new PowerBI V2 workspace, please check that you are not having a viewer level role because it gives only a read-only experience to it's users. You won't be able to save the reports and the API will give you 403 which is the Forbidden error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @parth-mangukiya.
I went thought the official documentation and there are multiple [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal#considerations-and-limitations) to it. Since few things were beyond my control to handle (Enterprise level changes involved), the idea of shared dataset had been deferred.